# Program output is different when executed through Powershell remote session

Tags: c++, visual-c++, powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm developing a Windows Console Application, using Visual Studio 2010, which prints progress percentage on screen such that the last number gets overwritten with the current number. I'm using carriage return to achieve this like so:

```
std::wcout
    << "[Running: "
    << std::setw(3)
    << std::setprecision(3)
    << percent
    << "%]"
    << '\r'
;
```

When I execute this program through PowerShell on a remote host using PSSesion:

```
Enter-PSSession WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ -credential <UserName>
[WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ]: PS C:\> .\test.exe
```

it behaves differently compared to when its executed locally either in PowerShell or in cmd.exe. I face following three problems:

1) The console output of the program is different, in that, instead of overwriting `[Running xx%]` its printing in the next line like so:

```
[Running  1%]
[Running  2%]
[Running  3%]
[Running  4%]
...
```

This is similar to what happens when output of a program is redirected to a file (lone `carriage returns` or `newlines` are replaced with `carriage returns`+`newlines` combinations).

2) The output doesn't shows up as and when the program writes something to cout. It comes at once at the end of execution. Does powershell caches the output of remote program and sends to the caller only once? If there is significant time difference between two lines (line meaning all the output between two `newline`s) then the first line gets printed as if it waits for some time for another `newline` and if received, it again goes to waiting state, if not received within certain time period (~500ms), it sends the output till last `newline` (and not all the accumulated output) to the caller. As can be seen from my code, there is no `newline` resulting in all the `[Running  xx%]` being printed at once at the end.

3) At certain point in the program I need user's confirmation, but `cin.fail()` returns `true` in remote execution. So, is there any way to take user input in such an execution environment? Or is there any way to detect that the program is being executed remotely through Powershell (eg. some env variable)?

Any help related to any point will be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: why did you tagged it as "c++" and "visual-c++" ?

Comment: @Solaflex : In the hope that there might be some c or c++ library api that can control this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to 1), the WinRM protocol for PowerShell Remoting is really just an input/output stream for commands and their serialized output. It has no terminal emulation capabilities, so when you run things remotely, their output is fed back sequentially one line at a time. If you used SSH or Telnet to a remote shell of powershell.exe, you would likely see what you expect.

As for 2), the default output buffermode appears to be "Block" so this would explain the behaviour you're seeing. You can change this with the `New-PSSessionOption` cmdlet to create a configuration for a session created by `New-PSSession` that can be passed to the -Session parameter on remoting aware cmdlets. The option is `OutputBufferingMode`. If you set it to `None`, you should get the desired behaviour.

```
# default output buffering mode is "none" for default options
$s = new-pssession localhost -sessionoption (new-pssessionoption)
enter-pssession $s
```

For 3), <strike>you should be able to accept input interactively IIRC.</strike> Looks like interactive stuff doesn't work right - I may have completely misremembered this.

Comment: For 1) If the output is simply fed back, how are '\r' getting replaced by '\r\n' sequence? For 2) Is there any way to turn it off or is it possible to flush the output from within the program? 3) As I said, cin stream is in an invalid state. Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: For 1), it's probably an artifact of the xml serialization/deserialization process. For 2) and 3), I'll try to get back to you later with POC.

Comment: I tried New-PSSessionOption but the result is still the same. From the description of `OutputBufferingMode`, it seems like it defines the behaviour in case of disconnected session and not the running sessions.